# change negative numbers to square bracket form in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to format the negative numbers so that it is surrounded by a square bracket with red color font in excel when I create it using `openpyxl`.

I am currently using manual function definition as shown below:

```py
def reformat_negative_number(num):
    if num > 0:
        return num
    else:
        return f"({str(num * -1)})""
```

```py
sheet["A1"].value = reformat_negative_number(-3.14)
```

Is there a better way, using `openpyxl` methods, to achieve this formatting? Thank you.

Comment: Read about [conditional-formatting](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html#conditional-formatting)

Comment: Something like work_sheet['A5'].number_format = '#.##;[Red](#.##);0.00;@' should work. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68 In that case the value of the cell doesn't change, just the format you see it in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [Named Style](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#named-styles) would work.

```py
from openpyxl import *
from openpyxl.styles import *
#from openpyxl.styles.colors import RED #optional import for color names
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("./document.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

negative_style = NamedStyle(name='negativeStyle')
negative_style.font = Font(color = '00FF0000') #or color = RED, using import above
negative_style.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="right")
wb.add_named_style(negative_style)

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1, max_row=10):
    if cell.value < 0:
        cell.value = f"({cell.value})" #If you want [ ] brackets, just change here to: f"[{cell.value}]"
        cell.style = negative_style
wb.save('document.xlsx')
```

**Output**

[image: Excel Output]

Or as mentioned in the comment below, you can use [Conditional Formatting](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html#conditional-formatting):

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import *
from openpyxl.formatting import Rule
from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill, Border, Alignment
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import CellIsRule

wb = load_workbook("./document.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

ws.conditional_formatting.add('A1:C10', CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0'],font = Font(color = '00FF0000')))

wb.save('document.xlsx')
```

Comment: Actually, this should be possible with the relevant number format directly which has options for like this.

Comment: @CharlieClark How do I add in the additional brackets/parens that OP wants? I have `ws.conditional_formatting.add('A1:C10', CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0'],font = Font(color = '00FF0000')))`